# DBConcurrency exception using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting an error performing what should be a simple enough task.

I am using Entity Framework 6 code first.

I am adding a new entity to my context, removing it and then performing a save. This produces a DBConcurrency exception (I am the only user).

To do this I perform the following:

**zurich.TagProjectGroupItems.Add(tagProjectGroupItem);
zurich.TagProjectGroupItems.RemoveRange(items);**

(the originally added object was part of the collection)

**int counter = zurich.SaveChanges();**

This generates the following exception:

**An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.**

The objectcontext tells me that I have 0 new entries, 0 updated and 1 to delete. I would imagine it is trying to remove the entity from the database and returning 0 results because the entity hadn't been written.

I am doing something glaringly wrong?! I have never previously used code first and have only used model first in EF4. I'm stumped.

Many thanks,

Rob

Comment: Are you saying that the items object which you are removing from the collection contains the 'tagProjectGroupItem' that you *just* added to the context?

Comment: Correct yes Ciaran. The ui allows the user to add an entity and also to remove/delete it. I could do remove but I get the same result obviously.

Comment: But why add the item to the context if you are going to remove the item immediately afterwards? Would the adding and removing of the entities not be separate events/handlers?

Comment: The user has a ui allowing he/she to add, delete and update entries in a grid. When the window is closed a save is performed. 

So the user may or may not actually do this (add and then delete) i.e. they may add an item and change their mind and remove it. I didn't particularly want to go off to the database every time an item is added as it seems very database-chatty. I was able to do this previously with EF 4 but not now?

Answer (score 0):

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException's are called "when it was expected that SaveChanges for an entity would result in a database update but in fact no rows in the database were affected." [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

I think EntityFramework performs this check to prevent concurrency issues in multi-user scenarios.

You could stick in another `zurich.SaveChanges();` just after adding the item and then it should successfully remove the items, but as you mention, this isn't ideal.

Perhaps instead you should check the collection of items - and if the tagProjectGroupItem is contained within the items, then don't call `zurich.TagProjectGroupItems.Add(tagProjectGroupItem);`, and instead remove the tagProjectGroupItem from the collection *before* calling the database operation.

Comment: I've managed to get round it by checking the entity state when removing it from the context. In the remove method if it is entitystate.added then i set it to detached. Therefore when the save is commenced the entity is detached and doesn't cause the issue. This seems to solve the problem but seems a bit hacky.